Why might `DeleteAll<<records>>` not delete the records?
I have an entity, WeeklyIpLoans that has a built-in DeleteAllWeeklyIpLoanss server action. I'm able to see records with "View or Edit Data" on the entity's contextual menu, and, given the filter I currently have, shows a single record (there are more in the entity):

It was created at approximately 1 AM local time.

My server action includes the DeleteAllWeeklyIpLoanss server action with a breakpoint set there.

When I debug and then step over this action, and then check the entity, the existing record is still there. I see no errors in the app's log.
In an attempt to troubleshoot this, I created a client action that has one step, the DeleteAllWeeklyIpLoanss server action. I placed it first in the OnInitialize client method (that triggers everything else). When I now debug and step over that DeleteAllWeeklyIpLoanss, the loan (and assuming all the loans) is deleted.


While it's nice to be able to delete all the records, I need it to happen in the server action (which, as you might guess, is executed via an event scheduled to execute overnight).
Note: If I, within the primary server action that doesn't delete all the records place a call to the new testing server action that appears to succeed, the delete fails. So if the call to delete all records is in my primary server action it seems to fail.
